# Name of complex number construction?

Tags: complex-numbers

From any ordered field $\mathcal{F}$, we may construct another field $K$ whose elements consist of ordered pairs of elements of $\mathcal{F}$, and whose addition and multiplication are defined by:

1. $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)$
2. $(a, b) \cdot (c, d) = (ac - bd, ad + bc)$

This is basically how you go from the reals to the complex numbers.

Is there a name for this process?

Comment: It would be a field extension. Not sure if there's a special name for that particular field extension when working over an arbitrary field.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal F$ is any field where $-1$ is not a square, and you identify $\mathcal F$ with $\mathcal F\times\{0\}\subset K$, note that $(0,1)\in K$ is precisely a square root of $-1$.

I'd say that $K=\mathcal F[i]$ or $\mathcal  F[\sqrt{-1}]$.